# JSFL: How to export movieclips so they can stream

Tags: flash, streaming, jsfl

I have a scenario where there are several movieclips within a single fla. I would like to export each movieclip as its own swf, but the catch is that I want to export it so that it can stream.

When exporting a normal .fla with movie content in the main timeline, the resulting swf is able to stream -- it can start playing before it has loaded 100%.

When I use the JSFL function: document.exportSWF([fileURI [, bCurrentSettings]]), the resulting .swf must load 100% before it can start playing. This is because it exports as a timeline with an instance of the movieclip. The main timeline is only one frame and the actual movie content is nested in that frame.

I'm wondering how, with JSFL (or any other way that's isn't manually copying the frames), to take a movieclip and export it to a swf that can stream, so that the movieclip itself IS the main timeline.

Answer (score 0):

It is a really nice question. My first thought, there can be a metaData like .mov streaming and it interrupts proper loading/playing until %100 loaded. Did you try Loader Object without event listeners?

Comment: Loading itself isn't the quite the issue. The issue is more a question of how do I export the movieclip has a top-level timline just like the main timeline of an .fla. Another way of phrasing the question is "How do I turn a movieclip into a main timeline?"